# How to print out JSON object in perl using AnyEvent::Twitter::Stream

Tags: perl, twitter

I'm using the AnyEvent::Twitter::Stream module to grab tweets.  Ultimately I'm trying to print the tweets to a file but I'm unable (I think) to get the tweet as a JSON object.  My code is as follows:

```
#!/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/perl

use AnyEvent::Twitter::Stream;
    my $done = AnyEvent->condvar;

BEGIN {
    use Exporter;
    our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
    our @EXPORT = qw{
       &init
    };
}

sub print_tweet {
  my $tweet = shift;
  print $tweet;   
}


  # receive updates from @following_ids
  my $listener = AnyEvent::Twitter::Stream->new(
      username => XXXXXX
      password => XXXXXX
      method   => 'sample',  # "firehose" for everything, "sample" for sample timeline
      decode_json => 1,
      on_tweet => sub {
          my $tweet = shift;
          print_tweet($tweet);
      },
      on_keepalive => sub {
          warn "ping\n";
      },
      on_delete => sub {
          my ($tweet_id, $user_id) = @_; # callback executed when twitter send a delete notification
      },
      timeout => 45,
  );

$done->recv;
```

Yet when I print out the tweet in the print_tweet subroutine all I get is:

```
HASH(0x8f0ad0)HASH(0x8f0640)HASH(0x875990)HASH(0x8f0ab0)HASH(0x8e0d80)HASH(0x8f06e0)HASH(0x8f08f0)HASH(0x93ef30)HASH(0x876190)HASH(0x93ee60)HASH(0x8f0610)HASH(0x8f0b00)HASH(0x8e13e0)HASH(0x93ee20)HASH(0x8f0a20)HASH(0x8e1970)HASH(0x8f0900)
```

I've even tried to print out the tweet assuming it is a hash as follows:

```
sub print_tweet {
  my ($jsonref, $tweet) = @_;
  my $tweet = shift;
  print %tweet;
}
```

Yet that produced nothing.  It appears that AnyEvent::Twitter::Stream is returning $tweet as an object based on their sample code of:

```
  on_tweet => sub {
      my $tweet = shift;
      warn "$tweet->{user}{screen_name}: $tweet->{text}\n";
  },
```

And I know I can print out individual objects, but can I get teh raw JSON object?  I must be missing something or my 'noob'ness is greater than I thought...

**UPDATE**

```
I was able to ALMOST get it by changing print_tweet to the following:

sub print_tweet {
  my $tweet = shift;
  my $json_output = to_json($tweet);
  print $json_output;
}
```

It prints out MOST of the JSON object but complains about wide characters, which I believe is an issue with the output being utf8 format?  I'm unsure how to solve this issue though....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  Need to use the JSON module and encode.  When encoding you **MUST** use the `{utf8 => 1}` option to account for the utf8 characters you get form Twitter.  Final code is here:

```
#!/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/perl

use JSON;
use utf8;
use AnyEvent::Twitter::Stream;
    my $done = AnyEvent->condvar;

BEGIN {
    use Exporter;
    our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
    our @EXPORT = qw{
       &init
    };
}

sub print_tweet {  
  my $tweet = shift;
  my $json_output = to_json($tweet, {utf8 => 1});
  print $json_output;
  print "\n";
}


  # receive updates from @following_ids
  my $listener = AnyEvent::Twitter::Stream->new(
      username => XXXXXXXX
      password => XXXXXXXX
      method   => 'sample',  # "firehose" for everything, "sample" for sample timeline
      on_tweet => sub {
          my $tweet = shift;
          print_tweet($tweet);
      },
      on_keepalive => sub {
          warn "ping\n";
      },
      on_delete => sub {
          my ($tweet_id, $user_id) = @_; # callback executed when twitter send a delete notification
      },
      timeout => 45,
  );

$done->recv;
```

Thanks to the help you guys gave, the DataDumper at least let me verify the format, it just didn't produce the final result.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it's returning a `hashref`. If you're not sure, you could try doing something like this.

```
use Data::Dumper;

...

print Dumper $tweet;
```

That should give you an idea of what's being passed, then you can grab what you want - probably something like this:

```
print "$tweet->{user}{screen_name}: $tweet->{text}\n";
```

Comment: This gives the structure but it does not give the original JSON object.

Answer (score 2):

In `print_tweet`, you're declaring `$tweet` twice. First, you assign it the second element of the `@_` array, then you redeclare it and assign it the *first* element of `@_`, because `shift` operated on `@_` by default.

Of course, if you had `use warnings` turned on, you would have seen

```
"my" variable $tweet masks earlier declaration in same scope
```

That's why you should **always** `use strict; use warnings;` at the top of your code.

The strings of output that you're seeing are hash references, the result of printing what's in the first argument to `print_tweet` (what you initially assign to `$json_ref`). If you want to print out the value of `$tweet`, get rid of the line where you clobber it with `shift`.

Comment: Sorry, I copied in the wrong version of my code, I have fixed it above.  $tweet is the first parameter I am sending to print_tweet and it is still a HASHREF.